# Аутентификация по номеру телефона Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, аутентификация

Решила написать простенькое приложение на телефон, требующее авторизации по номеру телефона, использую сервис аутентификации `Firebase`, но не могу почему то написать в программе объект `PhoneAuthProvider`. Андроид Студио его просто не видит и все. В чем может быть причина? Всем заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам надо, [согласно доке](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) подключить либу для авторизации:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
```